# How to represent edge weights in Dijkstra's algorithm using 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, graph, 2d, dijkstra

I want to be able to access the weights of an edge by doing this:

`int edgeWeightOfTwoVertexes = weights[vertexA][vertexB];`

`vertexA` and `vertexB` are objects from my `vertex` class. So how would I initialize the 2D vector to get this to work?

I've never seen a vector/array element being accessed by a non integer value so I would like to know if something like this is possible. If not, what other suggestions are there to store and quickly access the edge weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could represent an edge as

```
std::pair<int, int>  // first = source, second = destination
```

Then your edge weights could be

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> weights;
```

Where the key would be your edge (designated by the start and end node) and the value would be the cost. So you could say

```
int edgeWeightOfTwoVertexes = weights[{vertexA, vertexB}];
```

Otherwise if you wanted to stick with a 2D vector, you'd have a

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> weights;
```

Then you could access that like

```
int edgeWeightOfTwoVertexes = weights[vertexA][vertexB];
```

but know that in general these graphs end up **very** sparse and this is not an efficient use of memory.

**Edit**
If your vertexes are instances of some `Vertex` class, I would give each `Vertex` an id that goes from `0` to Number of vertexes, then you can use these to index

```
weights[vertexA.id][vertexB.id]
```

Comment: If I use the 2D vector the way you suggested, wouldn't the indexes of `vertexA` and `vertexB` have to be some sort of integer data type rather than a `vertex` object?

Comment: Oh I see. Also, what would be a better method to implement for sparse graphs in order to conserve memory? And I'm not talking about using a different shortest path algorithm.

Comment: There are many ways to store sparse matrices efficiently, these are called [sparse storage schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix). The way I suggested with `std::map` would be similar to the above link's "Dictionary of keys". These are independent of your shortest path algorithm, you can still use Dijkstra, these storage schemes merely modify how you look up an edge/node.